# Verb tenses when using will/would?

Tags: grammaticality, conditional-constructions

I have a question regarding what verb tenses to use when using "will" and "would".

So if I start my sentence using "will", do I need to stick to using will throughout my sentence? I was recently taught that I'm using conditionals if I'm using "will/would" and that I need to stick to the verb of the conditional verb.

I've always said the following, though.

> A: I **will** buy it if the price **goes** down.

> B: **I'll** buy it if I **have** money.
>   I **would** buy it if I **have** money.

Do you think it should have been this?

> A: I **will** buy it if the price **will** go down.

> B:  **I'll** buy it if I **will have** money.
>   I **would** buy it if I **had** money.

Similarly, I've always said the following.

> She **told** me that she **will** go grocery shopping tomorrow, but I **told** her I **won't** be able to go with her.

Should it be this instead?

> She **told** me that she **would** go grocery shopping tomorrow, but I **told** her I **wouldn't** be able to go with her.

Is it ungrammatical to mix tenses in conditional sentences?

Comment: "I would buy it if I had money." seems similar to "If I were rich, I would live on Long Island." which talks of something that will never happen. (I will never be rich and I will never live on Long Island.) I will let somebody else chime about that sentence.

Answer (score 2):

With conditionals (*IF ... THEN*), like your first example, the 'rule' (it's far more complicated, really, because some specific situations call for different constructions) is that the tense-bearing verb in the condition (*IF*) clause and *WILL* in the consequence (*THEN*) clause take the same past/non-past tense:

> If the price **goes** [*non-past*] up I **will** [*non-past*] buy it.
>   If the price **went** [*past*] up I **would** [*past*] buy it.
>   If the price **had** [*past*] gone [*perfect*] up I **would** [*past*] have bought [*perfect*] it.

It is the function (*IF* or *THEN*) of the clause, not its position in the sentence, which governs:

> I **will** [*non-past*] buy it if the price **goes** [*non-past*] up.
>   I **would** [*past*] buy it if the price **went** [*past*] up.
>   I **would** [*past*] have bought [*perfect*] it if the price **had** [*past*] gone [*perfect*] up.

Note that *will* here does not express tense; it implies consequence, not futurity. You may substitute *may/might* or *can/could* for *will/would* in all these examples.

The situtation is different in your 'shopping' example, where *will/would* in the subordinate clauses **does** express tense, and must be deployed accordingly. Let's look at two different situations:

> She told me last week that she would go grocery shopping yesterday, but I told her her I **would** not be able to go with her.

In this case the shopping trip was in the future when you spoke with her but is no longer in the future; you must employ the **past** form of *will*.

> She told me last week that she will go grocery shopping tomorrow, but I told her I **will** not be able to go with her.
>   She told me last week that she will go grocery shopping tomorrow, but I told her I **would** not be able to go with her.

In this case the shopping trip is still in the future; you **were** unable to accompany her then and you still **are** unable to accompany her. You may use either *will* or *would*, depending on which timeframe you want to communicate.

Comment: So if I'm not using "if...then" conditionals, I can mix tenses like in your shopping trip sentences? For example, "she 'told' me last week that she 'will' go...but I 'told' her I 'will' not..."?

Comment: @jess Yes, when they occur in different timeframes. As I said, it's complicated. "She told me last week that she **would** go shopping tomorrow" is also acceptable in all those examples.

Comment: I have another question. It's about saying "I knew I wouldn't/won't be able to do it" about an action that I will need to perform in the future. Since I'm reporting a past event but the action itself hasn't taken place yet, can I use either and be correct?

Comment: @jess Only _wouldn't_ is correct here. You cannot know if you can do it, unless it's passed, which in this case, you use _wouldn't_. It's a bit complicated, so let's take a timeline. 1, 2, 3, 4 being points in time. 1 is when you knew. 3 is the present. _I knew I wouldn't be able to do it_. This was confirmed at point 2. _I knew I won't be able to do it_. This tends to mean it is confirmed at point 4, but can you confirm the future? Since you cannot, it would be _I know I won't be able to do it_.

Comment: @Jerry On the other hand, you **can** say "I **didn't** know yesterday that I **will** be able to attend the conference after all."

Comment: Can you really? The 'being able to attend' changed (from not being able to attend) some time between yesterday up to now, has it not (hence future in the past)?

Comment: @Jerry "Hey, StoneyB, I saw your name on the conference list. You told me yesterday you wouldn't be there." "Well, the boss only just told me; so I didn't know yesterday that I *will* be able to go after all." Future in past just now, not the past then. Perfectly natural.

Comment: Hmm, I guess it's not as natural for me then ^^; I would respond _wouldn't_ with _would_.

Answer (score 1):

Between "I will buy it if the price goes down." and "I will buy it if the price will go down." only the first is idiomatic English.

*Would* is used as past tense of *will* when reporting something said or thought. "She told me that she would go grocery shopping tomorrow, but I told her that I wouldn't be able to go with her." is correctly using *would*, and it is similar to the following sentences:

> He said he would be here at eight o'clock.

> She asked if I would help.

> They told me that they probably wouldn't come.

Comment: So, when reporting something said or thought, I shouldn't use "will" like I did in my grocery shopping example?